# Two action function from one commandbutton

Tags: apex, commandbutton

I have implemented `prev << next>>` buttons also..

which will show me resultset part by part along with the sphere..

i've used SOQL Offset-limit logic..but the problem is when clicking prev or next button, pageblock containing the sphere disappears..

what i want is that while clicking prev or next button it will call the enablesphere method also, along with its own action function..

```
public void previous() {
  index = index - blockSize;enableSphere();
}
```

is not working..is there any way to call 2 functions from 1 button? please help

Comment: apex page clicking on a button need automatic click on another. Please help me out

Comment: Wrapping your two methods in one new one called e.g. `enableSphereAndPrevious` should work as long as you return the `previous` method return value (assuming that is a new page). But perhaps there is an issue with controller state when `enableSphere` executes; perhaps it was coded to work once your are on the new page not while the controller state still relates to the old page. Review that.

Comment: Complete tangent but have you looked at using the standard set controller to handle pagination? Much easier!

Answer (score 2):

Saikat
if you are trying to render a progress sphere while loading previous & next records you can use actionSupport with actionStatus to show the progress while the action is in progress

**reference :** 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm

you can also try using the rerender attribute in the actionsupport or in your commandbutton to show the sphere pageblocktable once your action is complete